# Reading Philipp Burkhardt's profession

Tags: palaeography, kurrent, german

I can't read the profession of Anna Maria's father.  My Kurrent is still not great, and I can't read the letters well enough to figure out a word that fits.  It sort of looks like it's "Bürger u. Salzhuford nach gr___ßin" or "Bürger u. Sapfuhord nach gr____ßin", but I could use some assistance from anyone who can read this better than I.  If it helps, the area had a salt mine; the Burkhardts of this area were generally salt-mining workers, leatherworkers, day laborers, mill workers, or potters.  In the record of Anna Maria's birth, he was listed as a "Bürger u. Taglöhner".

[image]

Here's another entry with what looks to be the same text for his occupation, from his wife's funeral record:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The profession is *Salzführer* (the final letter in the original is an end-s due to being in genitive case), which according to a quick internet search is a variant of *Salzfuhrmann*, i.e. a teamster or carter transporting salt.

The following words are *nachgelaßene Tochter* (modern spelling would be *nachgelassene*) and not part of the profession.